# Is there a verbose mode for PowerShell cmdlets?

Tags: powershell

Is there any general manner for observing the low-level details of what exactly is transpiring while running any given cmdlet in PowerShell?  The specific cmdlet doesn't matter, because this concerns finding a verbose mode that applies generally to all of them.  To clarify, this doesn't regard watching PowerShell scripts as they execute.  Is this possible with PowerShell cmdlets?

Comment: how about `-verbose`? or `-debug`?

Comment: As a very new beginner with Powershell at the simplest level, I hadn't heard of these yet.  But based on what I can now find concerning them, they seem to steer me in perhaps the right direction.  If I'm understanding them correctly, it seems that these can be appended to any cmdlet line in power shell and doing so will cause something along the lines of what I'm wanting to occur.  So thank you.

Comment: Be aware that the output of these switches depend on those who wrote the cmdlet/function/script. The powershell engine itself doesn't generate anything, so developers need to add these "comments". As a result, cmdlets from good developers have useful output, while others have none or useless output. The same goes for `-WhatIf`

Comment: Here's a good intro to how you can include verbose output in your own cmdlets using `write-verbose`: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/poshchap/2014/09/18/scripting-tips-and-tricks-write-verbose/.  Many existing cmdlets already contain such statements, so adding the `-verbose` switch will cause them to provide output.

Comment: Very helpful replies...thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O,

What I think might be of great value to you, is the PowerShell Help System.

It is one of the best out there!

Simply using `Get-Help about_commonparameters` will let out all of the common parameters available to every cmdlet in PowerShell

Will give you a great idea about the following Parameters:

```
-Debug
-ErrorAction
-ErrorVariable
-InformationAction
-InformationVariable
-OutVariable
-OutBuffer
-PipelineVariable
-Verbose
-WarningAction
-WarningVariable
-WhatIf
-Confirm
```

Hope this is useful!

Also here is a great [TechNet Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176848.aspx) on how to use the `Get-Help` functionality

Comment: I will definitely do this, then.  Thank you for these great pointers.   :)